# VBA Find problems - error when nothing found

Tags: excel, vba

I bet this is something simple.  Even though I've researched a lot and tried several methods I still get run time error 424.

The code is to find a number the user has entered. If the number is in the data set I want to do one thing but if the number is not in the data set I want to do something else.

Code is below.

```
Sub Test()

Dim Material As String
Dim cell As Range

    Material = InputBox("Enter BIS # for material type")

    Range("A7:a40").Select

       Set cell = Selection.Find(What:=Material, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    If cell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Boo"

    Else
        MsgBox "Great"

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `Activate` if `Find` returns nothing, so that will cause an error. Also, `Activate` is a sub, not a function, so you can't set `cell` to its return value.

**Note**: There's no need to `Select` the `Range("A7:A40")` for the `Find` function to work. You can fully qualify the `Range` that the `Find` function is searching for the specific value by using `Range("A7:A40").Find...`

Try this instead:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Material As String
    Dim cell As Range

    Material = InputBox("Enter BIS # for material type")     
    Set cell = Range("A7:A40").Find(What:=Material, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)             
    If cell Is Nothing Then ' <-- this lines checks if Find failed to find a match 
        MsgBox "Boo"
    Else
        cell.Activate
        MsgBox "Great"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, I've edited your answer, since there's no need to `Select` the `Range` for the `Find` function to work

Comment: Sometimes selection is a part of the UX, so I didn't touch it. But I'm sure OP can figure out what you did, and now they have a choice.

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks so much!